# How do I hide select text in excel (getting weird cells with conditional formatting)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

How do hide cells that contain text in excel?  These cells I am manually entering numbered data into them.  I'd like them to be invisible when containing SetNumber but when I enter data manually, the data is visible.

I have seen a number of [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39602381/trying-to-hide-text-in-an-excel-cell) solutions and this [solution](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Hide-or-display-cell-values-c94b3493-7762-4a53-8461-fb5cd9f05c33) which did not work.  My question is how do I hide columns A, B and C which all contain SetNumber?

[image]

I have used conditional formatting but for some reason the output appears very un-natural.  Is there a simple alternative?

[image]

Comment: If it's just columns you want to hide, just use `If ( your condition) Then
  Range("A:C").EntireColumn.Hidden = True` to hide columns A through C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete my comment above, you can do (in VBA):

```
Dim celltxt As String
celltxt = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Text
If InStr(1, celltxt, "SetNumber") Then
Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
EndIf
```

To hide Column A based upon the contents of cell A1. You should be able to modify this to suit your needs.